# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBOundsException Error what did i do wrong

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse

```
public int countMatchesWithRightShift(DNAStrand other, int shift){

    for (j = 0; j < (data.length()); ++j){
        other.data.charAt(j = other.data.charAt(j)+shift);
    }
        for (i = 0; i <other.length()-data.length(); ++i){

    if (other.data.charAt(i) == 'T' && data.charAt(i) == 'A'){
        rightShift++;
    }
    else if (other.data.charAt(i) == 'A' && data.charAt(i) == 'T'){
        rightShift++;
    }
    else if (other.data.charAt(i) == 'C' && data.charAt(i) =='G'){
        rightShift++;
    }
    else if (other.data.charAt(i) == 'G' && data.charAt(i) =='C'){
        rightShift++;
    }
}

    return rightShift;
}
```

This is for comparing two different DNA strands after one is shifted over by an int amount.
When I run the specchecker given to us the tests keep giving me the out of bounds error. im not sure what I have done wrong

Comment: which line is the error occuring?

Comment: Quite hard to see from just the information provided. Can you post the stack trace and or the rest of the code? But as the title suggests i assume other.data is at some point of a smaller length than what you expect.

Comment: why is marked as javascript?

Comment: Could you please correct the typo with the parantheses inside the first for loop. Funny enough, it might compile and run.

Comment: @user2310289 You are right! Maybe it is not a typo after all :P

Answer (score 1):

This line is dodgy

```
other.data.charAt(j = other.data.charAt(j)+shift);
```

do you mean to set the value of a char in a string by doing

```
other.data.charAt(j) = other.data.charAt(j)+shift;
```

well this is also not possible as strings are immutable

try

```
String other.data = other.data.substring(0,j) + other.data.charAt(j)+shift 
                      +other.data.substring(j + 1);
```

// warning test for indexes being off (no IDE here)